# Add a Static Framework to Pod.

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a pod in which I want to include a static framework. When I add a framework `.dependency` in `.podspec`:

`s.dependency 'Static_Framework', '~> 1.0.0'`

I get an error:

`- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (The 'App' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/private/var/folders/bc/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20171010-28205/Pods/Static_Framework/Frameworks/Static_Framework.framework)) during validation.`

Is it possible to add a static framework to a pod? If yes, what is the proper way to do it?

Or could I add that framework to the project together with my pod to make my pod working?

```
pod 'Static_Framework', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'My_Pod', '~> 0.1.0'
```

Because now when I add my pod to the project without describing a `Static_Framework` in `s.dependency` I get a build error `No such module 'Static Framework`' in my pod files.

Comment: They discussed this issue on Github. You can look up Cocoapods 1.4.0 Beta.

Comment: So it should be fixed in Cocoapods 1.4.0?

Comment: You can look forward https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6889

Answer (score 0):

In a .podspec file, above the line:

```
s.dependency 'Static_Framework', '~> 1.0.0'
```

Add:

```
s.static_framework = true
```

when using CocoaPods version 1.4.0 and above everything should work fine!

Comment: This is not working for me when I use GoogleSignIn as a dependency. I get an Xcode error `unsealed contents present in the bundle root`.